# How to pass event object to the event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am attaching a document key press event like

```
$(document).live("keypress",myObject.onDocumentKeyPress);
```

and my handler implementation is

```
onDocumentKeyPress:function(e){
              if(e.keyCode == 13) { //Enter keycode
                    myobject.onColumnOptionClick(null,true);
             }
        }
```

,

Now in this function am getting `e is not defined`.

How can pass event object to event handler?

I got a suggestion that

```
$(document).live("keypress",function(e){
    myObject.onDocumentKeyPress(e);
});
```

but in this case I will find difficult to unbind that particular handler.

Please suggest me a way.

Comment: PLEASE USE .ON INSTEAD OF LIVE . AS LIVE IS DEPRICATED NOW

Comment: and for unbinding you can simply use .off of jquery

Comment: Also, the document is always available, so there's no need for delegated event handlers at all ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fine:

```
$(document).on("keypress",function(e){
    myObject.onDocumentKeyPress(e);
});
```

---

> **You said** : but in this case I will find difficult to unbind that particular handler.

And for unbinding it, use **namespace** when attaching event handler:

```
$(document).on("keypress.something",function(e){
    myObject.onDocumentKeyPress(e);
});
```

Now you can unbind the event handler with that namespace:

```
$(document).off("keypress.something");
```

- `.live()` is deprecated in version 1.7, and removed in version 1.9. Use `.on()` instead.

---

References:

- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - jQuery API Documentation

---

As **@adeneo** said in comments, the event is always passed automagically:

```
$(function () {
    var o = {
        f: function (e) {
            alert(e.keyCode);
        }
    }

    $(document).on("keypress", o.f);
});
```

You can check the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NFVx7/1/). So the problem is elsewhere which you get error `e is not defined`. Try replacing your jQuery version with `1.7+` and use `.on()` method.

Comment: The event is always passed automagically, so the anonymous function is totally unneccessary

Comment: If the error is really `e is not defined`, how does this solve it?

Comment: @bfavaretto - it doesn't !

Comment: @adeneo Yes, you are **exactly** right, I confused at that moment. But the question is strange, the OP said I get `e is not defined`, and then, said that if use anonymous function it works, but the problem is with unbinding it... :~|

Answer (score 2):

```
var myobject = {
  onDocumentKeyPress: function (e) {
    console.log('Event ', e);
  }
};

$(document).live('keypress', myobject.onDocumentKeyPress);
```

This will and does get `e` as Event Object.

As NOX pointed out, the issue might be you using jQuery 1.9, in which `live` is removed. Try replacing `live` with `on`.

Comment: Agreed. Your code works fine on JQuery 2 using "on" instead of "live". See here: http://jsfiddle.net/judeosborn/RCJH8/